# Single-word verb for "to keep private/confidential"

Tags: single-word-requests, derivation

What would be a single-word verb for 'to keep private/confidential'?

My first thought was the verb "to privatise" but it doesn't connote this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can *[classify](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/classify)* information: designate (documents or information) as officially secret or to which only authorized people may have access; to limit the availability of (information, a document, etc.)

one can secrete or [*secretize*](http://www.ccplaw.com/attorneys/zitrin/Why_Lawyers_Keep_Secrets_About_Public_Harm.pdf) (very few uses) used by some, such as the attorney discussing the ethics of keeping information from the public: Why Lawyers Keep Secrets About Public Harm

One can *conceal* information, *suppress* it, *hide* it, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The word **protect** could work for this, depending on context. I work in protecting data and information and this is the term we use.

Answer (score 1):

Try the phrasal verb "hush up": to keep from public knowledge :  suppress (hush the story up)

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hush

Comment: Or the verb "supress" itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the word **conceal** and it's [variations](http://thesaurus.com/browse/conceal)

Comment: Could be a very useful comment. However, it's not an answer.

Comment: @Kris is that better?

Answer (score -1):

If the context is formal and technical, the natural choice would be *confidentialize* (do not look that one up in the dictionary, though, it won't probably be there for now.)

Space-Time Research, [SuperSTAR](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/data/information-agenda/A-Space-Time_Research_SuperSTAR_DM-DB2.pdf) (IBM IMS) [pdf]

> The Su-perSTAR suite helps organizations source data from various data sources, channel information into a high-speed database, **confidentialize** and protect the data, and provide tabulation, analysis, visualization and mapping tools for various user personas.

Answer (score -1):

Keep your information private = confidentialize

used in the context of as a ghostwriter I won't reveal client identity.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please [edit] to add [citations to reliable sources](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or [deleted](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).